# Using LEDs in a bridge rectifier circuit

Tags: led

How would I wire 4 LEDs so they would serve as their own bridge rectifier? I have a limited space (the interior of a bicycle taillight fixture) so I would like to use the LEDs themselves to rectify the A.C. coming from a bicycle wheel generator.

Also, to limit the current so as not to exceed the forward current to each LED, how would I calculate the resistor(s) value?

Comment: Is it 12V gen?  Any other loads planned? Consider the LED's like charging a battery. Each LED has a cell voltage so you want the charger slightly higher, usch as 14V on a 12V. White led's are 3.2 Vtyp and Red are 1.6 Vtyp unless they are high current types then higher voltage drop can be expected. Back to back is fine, but for the same power rather than dissipate in the resistor drop, this is the optimal way to match the load to the source. But your source is highly variable, so you can experiment with various back to back strings which will Clamp your generator voltage like zeners back toback

Answer (score 11):

LEDs typically have much lower reverse breakdown voltage limits ([Vrrm = 5 to 15 Volts](http://www.chml.com/products/pdf/1-78.pdf)) than even the cheapest, smallest silicon diodes ([1n4001](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds28002.pdf) = 50 Volts , [1n4007](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds28002.pdf) = 1000 Volts, [1n4148](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/1N4148_1N4448.pdf) = 100 Volts).

[image: 1n4001 Diode] ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N4001_and_1N5400_series_diodes))

Forward voltage Vf on the other hand is anywhere from 1.7 Volts for some red LEDs, to 3.5 Volts or higher for some blue and white ones. Compare this to a typical 0.7 Volt Vf for a standard silicon rectification diode.

In a full bridge rectifier configuration, the voltage is dropped by 2 x Vf during the forward conduction part of the cycle.

Thus if you were to build a bridge rectifier with LEDs, the output voltage would drop anywhere from 3.4 to 7 Volts or more, compared to the input. The conduction would start much later into the positive part of the cycle (once the voltage rises above the LED Vf), compared to a silicon diode. It would also end earlier. Also, during the reverse part of the cycle, depending on the specific LED used, the "diode" is likely to enter conduction well within the input voltage range.

In other words, the bridge will provide voltage during a much smaller part of the AC cycle than with silicon diodes, and will provide a lower voltage even then.

As your purpose seems to be actually lighting the LEDs rather than just rectifying the voltage, the output of the bridge may not matter, but it's useful to know.

A suggested alternative if you are keen to use LEDs in this particular way, is to hook up the LEDs as you desire, but to add one inexpensive and tiny 1n4001 or similar, in series the current limit resistor and each LED. The diodes are not much bigger than the discrete resistors you will probably use.

**Why this works**:
The silicon diodes will block reverse voltage better than an LED can, i.e. to a much higher voltage.

However, the **recommendation** remains to use just an [integrated 4-lead bridge IC](http://www.jameco.com/1/1/3113-df08m-diode-bridge-rectifier-1a-800v-dip-4.html) (35 cents single unit, **800 Volts/1 Ampere**), and use the LEDs as in any DC circuit configuration. Space requirement will not go up significantly.

### [image: DIP=4 bridge rectifier, 800 Volts 1 Ampere]

**Regarding current limiting resistor calculation**:

Obtain the peak voltage of the bicycle dynamo's AC signal, using a multimeter with either peak AC voltage mode if available, or RMS AC voltage (more common in basic multimeters) and multiplying by 1.4142 to estimate the peak voltage. All this while pedalling as fast as you can with the cycle on its stand.

Add in a safety factor by doubling this peak voltage if you are concerned about blown LEDs due to high voltage when speeding downhill, for instance. LEDs are somewhat forgiving of minor current spikes if they are for brief durations - It isn't over-current that kills an LED usually, it is inability to get rid of generated heat.

Now, if Vmax is your safety-adjusted peak voltage, subtract your LED Vf from it (2 x Vf if you are going with the bridge, 2 x (Vf + 0.7) if you add in the silicon diodes), to obtain the voltage Vres each resistor needs to drop.

R = Vres / I,

So plug in the recommended current I for your LED of choice, and you have your numbers.

LEDs commonly come in 5 mA (SMD and some 3mm ones), 20 mA, 25 mA or in the region of amperes (e.g. [Osram "Golden Dragon" LEDs](http://catalog.osram-os.com/media/_en/Graphics/00043703_0.pdf)). Refer to appropriate datasheets.

Comment: Anindo- Thanks for your response with its explanations and recommendations.

Comment: There is an incorrect saying in the answer: "dynamo's AC signal". As he wants to use a rectifier diode bridge, it's presumable he has an AC generator, so you meant "alternator's AC signal".

Answer (score 7):

As you suspect, you can skip the bridge rectifier altogether and have the LEDs rectify the current for you:

[image: Generator connected to two strings of series, antiparallel LEDs through a resistor]

When the current is flowing one way, only one string of LEDs will light.  When it's flowing the other way, only the other string will light.  As long as one string is always lit, then the reverse voltage on the other string will be kept low enough as not to damage the unlit LEDs.  Since only one string is lit at a time, only one resistor is needed.

You can add more LEDs, up to the voltage of your generator, in each string, just make sure there are the same number of LEDs in each string (to avoid the reverse voltage breakdown issue).  So if you're using 1.7V red LEDs, and a 12V generator, you can have 7 LEDs in each string - or just one LED on each side if you only need a total of two LEDs.

The resistor calculation is annoying in this case due to the varying voltage of the generator.  If there are no other loads on the generator (such as a headlight) you might see some pretty high voltages.

However, LEDs are pretty robust, and so you don't have to be exact to get a good result.

If you use the circuit above with two red LEDs in each string, and your generator is rated for 12V output, you will see about 8.6V across the resistor (12 - 1.7 - 1.7) under ideal conditions.  If the resistors are rated for 20mA, then you'll want a resistor that consumes 20mA when 8.6V is across it.  Plugging that into ohms law, `V = IR`, `8.6 = 0.20 * R`, gives `R = 430` so you'll want something around 430 ohms for the resistor.  470 ohms is a common value, and is suitable for this circuit.

When the generator has no other load, it might generate higher voltages.  Chances are you'll be fine, but if you notice your taillight not working, you should measure the voltage of the generator with a 470 ohm resistor across it, and plug that voltage in for 12V above to determine a better resistor value.

Comment: This is exactly the approach that I would take, given the desire to minimize parts count.  The downside is that only one pair of LEDs is lit at any one time, so half the useful amount of light is emitted.